# KeyStore not initialized from file

Tags: java, android

When I try to load (KeyStore method) previously saved data in keyStore I receive `EOFException`. File is created and data was save in it (store method from KeyStore). I would like to know what I should change in code to obtain data from file.
Saving (create a file, create Entry, etc.) :

```
  @Override
    public boolean savePIN(Context context, int pin) throws StorageAlreadyInitializedException {
        boolean containKey;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        if (mKeyStore == null) {
            initializeKeyStore(context);
        }
        if (mKeyStore != null) {
            try {
                containKey = mKeyStore.containsAlias(PASSWORD_ALLIAS);
                //if key is  in keystore then throw exception
                if (containKey) {
                    throw new StorageAlreadyInitializedException();
                }
                SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM_TYPE).generateKey();
                KeyStore.PasswordProtection password = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection((pin + "").toCharArray());
                KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);

                Log.v(TAG, "Secret key" + secretKey.toString() + " Secret Key encoded " + secretKey.getEncoded().toString());
                mKeyStore.setEntry(PASSWORD_ALLIAS, secretKeyEntry, password);
             //   mKeyStore.setKeyEntry(PASSWORD_ALLIAS,pinByte,null);
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), KEYSTORE_NAME);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // FileOutputStream
                mKeyStore.store(bOut, (pin + "").toCharArray());
                if (bOut != null) {
                    outputStream.write(bOut.toByteArray());
                }
                // Log.v(TAG, "savePin " + (pin + "").toCharArray());
                Key key = mKeyStore.getKey(PASSWORD_ALLIAS, (pin + "").toCharArray());
                Log.v(TAG, "output stream: " + outputStream.toString());
                Log.v(TAG, "Created key: " + key.getEncoded().toString());
            } catch (... e) {
              More exceptions...
```

loading:

```
  private void initializeKeyStore(Context context, int pin) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), KEYSTORE_NAME);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            mKeyStore.load(inputStream, (pin + "").toCharArray());
        }catch(...exceptions){}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Calling `File.createNewFile()` before `new FileOutputStream()` is both completely pointless and wasteful.
- Calling it before `new FileInputStream()` is positively counterproductive. All it accomplishes is turning a `FileNotFoundException` into an `EOFException.`
- The `ByteArrayOutputStream` is also pointless and wasteful here, and `bOut` cannot possibly be null at the point you're testing it. Just write directly to the file.
- The `EOFException` you're getting probably means the file is empty, which in turn probably means that `new FileOutputStream(...)` threw an exception which you haven't noticed, or else you never called it at all and the file didn't exist until you pointlessly created it before opening it for input.

Don't write code like this. I suggest you fix all this and retest. I have no doubt that the problem you report here will disappear. *Another* problem may well then surface, masked at present by all this.